# Multitenant WebRoles in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, multi-tenant

I am attempting to set up a multitenant application using Azure. This is how I imagine the architecture:

**WebRole** - single application for multiple users (each user requires custom hostnames e.g. *your.site.com* or *my.site.com* or *yoursite.com*)

**WorkerRole** - used to generate new database/add hostname to web role?

*The reasoning behind using WebRoles and WorkerRoles is for scalability.*

I know that you can add multiple hostnames to a webrole in the csdef like so:

```
<Sites>
   <Site name="Site1" physicalDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project1">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="domain1.com" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" hostHeader="domain1.com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Site2" physicalDirectory="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project2">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="domain2.com" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" hostHeader="domain2.com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="SSLName" />
</Endpoints>
```

this however requires you to have your sites already defined, I want to be able to dynamically add hostnames at any point and persist them (so when it auto scales it picks them up). The idea is that when a user signs up for the application, the worker role picks this up and adds the hostname somewhere (maybe the webrole IIS?).

I don't know if this is the right approach for doing this or if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, this is not the right approach. The primary reason being VMs hosting web/worker roles are **`Stateless VMs`**.

In order for your approach to work, you would need to create the sites for each customer using IIS API and because these VMs are stateless these sites will be removed when you either deploy the new code or the VM goes down for any reason and Microsoft has to replace it.

Furthermore, anytime you would horizontally scale the VM by adding new web role instances, you would have to create these sites again once the VM is up and running.

Comment: So would it make more sense to have the application on it's own normal VM and have a shared IIS Config?

Comment: Azure Virtual Machines would make more sense as these are **`Stateful VMs backed by Azure Blob Storage`**.